# When does cv.contourArea(contour, True) return a negative value?

Tags: opencv

The [documentation for `cv.contourArea`](https://docs.opencv.org/master/d3/dc0/group__imgproc__shape.html#ga2c759ed9f497d4a618048a2f56dc97f1) says that if `oriented` is `true`, the returned value will be positive or negative depending on the orientation of the contour:

> `oriented`: Oriented area flag. If it is `true`, the function returns a signed area value, depending on the contour orientation (clockwise or counter-clockwise). Using this feature you can determine orientation of a contour by taking the sign of an area. By default, the parameter is `false`, which means that the absolute value is returned.

However, it doesn't say what a negative value *means* - is the negative value for clockwise or for counterclockwise?

Comment: Why not write a short little script and test it out? Took about a minute.

Comment: @DanMašek Because eventually someone else will look this up and find out the answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The easiest way to get an answer to your question is to test this out with two simple triangle contours, one clockwise, one counterclockwise.

```
import numpy as np
import cv2

cw = np.array([[0,0],[4,0],[0,4]])
ccw = np.array([[0,0],[0,4],[4,0]])

print cv2.contourArea(cw, True)
print cv2.contourArea(ccw, True)
```

This prints out

```
8.0
-8.0
```

Hence, positive result means clockwise, negative counterclockwise.